# AWS Route 53 health check keeps alarming from inactive region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have a Route 53 health check with all the regions selected except US East (N. Virginia). However, it keeps alarming from that region from time to time. Why's that? Here's the alarm config:

[image]

Here's an example of the alarm:

```
You are receiving this email because your Amazon CloudWatch Alarm "***********-Low-HealthCheckStatus" in the US East (N. Virginia) region has entered the ALARM state, because "Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [0.0 (12/04/18 14:01:00)] was less than the threshold (1.0)." at "Thursday 12 April, 2018 14:02:29 UTC".

View this alarm in the AWS Management Console:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/home?region=us-east-1#s=Alarms&alarm=**************************-Low-HealthCheckStatus

Alarm Details:
- Name:                       ******************************
- Description:                
- State Change:               OK -> ALARM
- Reason for State Change:    Threshold Crossed: 1 datapoint [0.0 (12/04/18 14:01:00)] was less than the threshold (1.0).
- Timestamp:                  Thursday 12 April, 2018 14:02:29 UTC
- AWS Account:                ******************************

Threshold:
- The alarm is in the ALARM state when the metric is LessThanThreshold 1.0 for 60 seconds. 

Monitored Metric:
- MetricNamespace:                     AWS/Route53
- MetricName:                          HealthCheckStatus
- Dimensions:                          [HealthCheckId =************]
- Period:                              60 seconds
- Statistic:                           Minimum
- Unit:                                not specified



State Change Actions:
- OK: 
- ALARM: [arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:***********************]
- INSUFFICIENT_DATA:
```

I've really got bored of this. How to fix it? I need health checks only from Europe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are misinterpreting the meaning of this part of the alarm message.  Route 53 checks alarms always come from us-east-1, regardless, because Route 53 is operationally based out of us-east-1.  All the global health checkers funnel their test results back there for aggregation at a central point.  Being based in us-east-1, it communicates with CloudWatch only in us-east-1, and stores the metrics there.

> [in the console, select] US East (N. Virginia). Route 53 metrics are not available if you select any other region as the current region.
>
> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/monitoring-health-checks.html

*"Amazon CloudWatch Alarm "...-Low-HealthCheckStatus" in the US East (N. Virginia) region..."*

This does not mean the us-east-1 region is testing your endpoint or detecting the failure. The us-east-1 region's ability to reach your service is not being tested if that region is not in your configurarion.

Your health check *metrics* are stored in the US East (N. Virginia) region (us-east-1) because that is where *all* Route 53 health check metrics are stored, so that's how the message is always tagged.

But your health check is failing for reasons unrelated to us-east-1.  In the Route 53 console, you can see the most recent failure from each regional health checker and you should find that your site does have some kind of reachability issue that is occurring.

Comment: That does make sense, but really confusing though. As a user I don't care where they process my metrics, is there any reason they put this "in US East (N. Virginia)" into the email subject?

Comment: I see what you are saying, but Route 53 Health Check alarms are actually Cloudwatch metric alarms, and Cloudwatch metrics alarms list the Cloudwatch region in the alert message.  If you wanted to go look at the history of the metric directly in the Cloudwatch console, us-east-1 is where you'd need to go in order to find it.

Comment: You can also use [Axibase TSD](https://github.com/axibase/atsd-use-cases/tree/master/how-to/aws/route53-email-notifications#enhancing-alerts-with-axibase-time-series-database) to customize CloudWatch email alerts, for example by attaching a 24-hour availability chart to the email message/Slack message. The `message.region` tag can be left out to eliminate any misinterpretation.

Answer (score 1):

`us-east-1` is the region where the 'global' health percentage metric is calculated based on statuses collected by distributed nodes located in 'Health Checker Regions'.

The cloud watch alarm therefore is produced in `us-east-1`.